# How to switch between increasing and decreasing opacity for items in an array?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

### Goal & Problem

I'm building a project where a user is painting squares on a canvas. Currently when the mouse hovers over a square it will increase in opacity.

My goal is to alternate between painting and erasing mode via they keyboard keys `p` and `e`. However I cannot figure out how to decrease the opacity again. How do I implement this feature?

live example: https://brampijper.github.io/canvas-etch-a-sketch/

### Things I've tried

I've tried to decrease the opacity by simply using the minus operator, but that didn't work.

```
parseFloat(opacity) - 0.01;
```

Probably because the opacity is zero, instead of the actual opacity of the square.

### My current code:

These are the properties of one square object. (opacity = 0)

```
squares.push({
    xPos: squareSize * i,
    yPos: squareSize * x,
    xSize: squareSize,
    ySize: squareSize,
    color: 'rgb(0,0,0,0)'
})
```

This is where the color get's updated if the user is hovering over a square.

```
squares.filter(function (square) {
    if (square.xPos == row && square.yPos == column) {
        square.color = `rgb(0,0,0, ${opacity(0)})`;
        updateCanvas(square)
    } 
})

function opacity(opacity) {
    if(painting) return parseFloat(opacity) + 0.01;
    else return parseFloat(opacity) - 0.01;
}

function updateCanvas(square) {
    ctx.fillRect(square.yPos, square.xPos, square.xSize, square.ySize)
    ctx.fillStyle = square.color;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'e') {
        painting = false
        console.log('switch to eraser')
    }
    if (event.key == 'p') {
        painting = true
        console.log('switch to paintbrush')
    }
})
```

I expect that when the user switches to eraser mode (`e` on the keyboard) the opacity of the squares should decrease by 0.01 on mouse hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should have the opacity saved to (and modified on) the `square` object. As is, your `opacity()` function is always given `0`.

```
squares.push({
   xPos: squareSize * i,
   yPos: squareSize * x,
   xSize: squareSize,
   ySize: squareSize,
   color: 'rgb(0,0,0,0)',
   opacity: 0.01
 })
```

and then pass the whole square to the opacity function so it can be modified.

```
square.color = `rgb(0,0,0, ${opacity(square)})`;
```

...

```
// this returns an increased opacity value on mousehover.
function opacity(square) {
    if(!eraserActive){
      square.opacity += 0.1;
    }else{
      square.opacity -= 0.1;
    }
    return square.opacity;
}
```

Then you need to clear the existing square before drawing a new one.

```
function updateCanvas(square) {
    // CLear it and draw a new one..
    ctx.clearRect(square.yPos, square.xPos, square.xSize, square.ySize);
    ctx.fillStyle = square.color;
    ctx.fillRect(square.yPos, square.xPos, square.xSize, square.ySize)
}
```

Here's a working fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/xwg5vzs8/

---

note that when using the jsfiddle, in order for your key events to be heard, you need to first click on the output frame.

Comment: I believe You have to set `fillStyle` before call to `fillRect`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I didn't know about clearing the existing canvas elements (still learning about canvas). Thanks a lot for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the opacity using

`document.getElementById(#id).style.opacity = _opacity;`

Here _opacity is the variable to store the current opacity value and #id is the id of the element for which the opacity needs to be updated

Comment: you can't use css to style a specific portion of the canvas like that. each individual square doens't have an id. only the entire canvas has an id.